# Lucene and External DB

Tags: java, derby, lucene

I am working with the Lucene and Derby databases. Lucene contains the text index, and Derby has information regarding additional user data. For example, each document has a tag. For this purpose the Derby database has two tables

**TAGS**:

ID

Name

**LUCENETAGS**:

ID

LUCENEID (docID in Lucene, not a field)

TAGID

I want a user to be able to search something like:

> very interesting text AND **tag:fun**

Changing the structure in a way that tag is a Lucene field is not an option.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll have to simply perform your text search in Lucene, and then filter your results based on the result of a query into a Derby.

If few documents will match a particular tag, you could also query the database for the IDs to be queried, and rewrite the query like:

```
(very interesting text) AND id:(1 2 3 etc.)
```

Probably not feasible, but in the case that tags are pretty sparse, it might be worth considering.

I do wonder, though, why a field can't be added to the index, duplicating the stored value in the Derby Database.  In any implementation you choose to get what you want from your stated structure, you will see much poorer performance, and more complexity for you to deal with, than if the data were available in the index as well.

Comment: I have tried id field in Luke, but it doesnt work. Do you know maybe a build-it field for Doc ID in Lucene?
Another question is which class shall i extend in order to parse custom fields and substitute it like that? On the side note, I havent developed the backend so thats the only reason why i cannt change it, but I agree 100% with u ;)